# Possibility of computing a and b values from the ciphertext?

Tags: factoring, paillier

Using paillier encryption, $N$ is the product of two large prime numbers, $s$ is sampled randomly from $Z_{N^2}$ we get $ C \leftarrow g^ms^N \bmod N^2 $ where $g=1+N$, By multiplying the cipher $c$ and a prime number $B$, we get the following equation:

$g^az^N = CB \bmod N^2$

Is it possible to compute the value of $a$ and $z$ ?

Comment: Is the question asking to compute a valid $(a,z)$? If so what is assumed known? I guess that includes $N$, $g$, $c$, and $B$, but is there anything else, e.g. the factorization of $N$, or/and $s$?

Comment: The question is edited. The question is to compute a valid $(a,z)$ such that the equation holds using the factorization of $N$.  Values $B$, $N$, $g$, $C$, and $s$ are assumed to be known.

Comment: Hint: Since the factorization of $N$ is known, we can use the procedure in Paillier decryption. Independent note: $s$ does not seem needed, and would not usually be in a Paillier encryption context.